# The inline attachment i save to disk is corrupted

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have a piece of code that read my inbox email. the code identify 2 kind of attachments:

1) The attached files, which are downloaded and saved to a database. This works just fine.

2) The inline attachment (I'm using an image as the attachment in my tests). The code detects this kind of attachment, but when I save them to disk the file seems to be corrupted. I checked the file properties generated and noticed that it had no basic info (pixels, height, width) with it. I think the file is not saved properly when downloaded to disk (I have tried PNG and JPG). I think the file needs to be saved with a kind of  mimetype properties so i can open it properly. Any tips please? Thanks in advance.!

Here is a snip of my code:

```
public void procesMultiPart(Multipart content) throws SQLException {

    try {

        for (int i = 0; i < content.getCount(); i++) {
            BodyPart bodyPart = content.getBodyPart(i);
            Object o;
            String downloadDirectory = "D:/Attachment/";

            o = bodyPart.getContent();
            if (o instanceof String) {
                System.out.println("procesMultiPart es plainText");

            } else if (null != bodyPart.getDisposition() && bodyPart.getDisposition().equalsIgnoreCase(Part.ATTACHMENT)) {
                    System.out.println("IS ATTACHMENT...");
                    // i save the attachment to database and is OK..
            } else if (bodyPart.getDisposition() == null){
                System.out.println("IS AN INLINE ATTACHMENT...");
                String fileNameinline = "inline" + i + ".png";
                InputStream inStream = bodyPart.getInputStream();
                FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(downloadDirectory + fileNameinline), true);
                byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[4096];// 4 KB
                int numRead;
                while ((numRead = inStream.read(tempBuffer)) != -1) {
                    outStream.write(tempBuffer);
                }
                inStream.close();
                outStream.close();                  
            }

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you send yourself an image as an attachment both ways, so that you'd already know it was a .jpg (or whatever type you choose)?

Comment: Then open both files with a text editor, and see if they start off and/or end the same.  You may be missing file headers or something on the broken one.

Comment: @DeanJ, i send my self an image as inline, (i use printscreen and past it directly to the message body), send the email and then i try to capture the inline attachment i just send. Remember that normal attachment is working fine , just the inline attachment are broken.

Comment: @DeanJ i guess i know where my problem is. look: i did what you said. i capture a screen and save it to a file as PNG, and use the same capture and paste it in a email body as inline image. when compare both files the structure is diferrent (the good png is not readeable in notepad, and the one downoaded from email is readable text). please see the link : http://1drv.ms/1fWlkmN

Comment: So obviously you're sending the image as an IMG inside an HTML page, and when you save the attachment you're just saving HTML. So don't do that. So the problem is at the sending end, or is at least a disagreement between what is being sent and what is being expected at the receiver.

Comment: @EJP you are right, but i don't know why. i just paste an image in the mail! do you know how can i identify the image in the inline so i can just save teh image and not the rest ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for help and tips. I solved the problem. This is how i did it:  I notice that when read the email body (where supposes there was just the pasted image) , there was more that just the image, there was a kind of HTML too, so in other words, the body part has multiparts (2 parts in my case), so i have to process each part until find the image, so i can save it.
hope this help someone else.
regards.

Answer (score 1):

The file is corrupted because you are writing it to the disc incorrectly:

```
outStream.write(tempBuffer);
```

You should only write as many bytes as you read:

```
outStream.write(tempBuffer, 0, numRead);
```

Comment: Thanks @Aron for your reply. i have made the change you suggest, but the result is the same, the file seems corrupt. i have tried with jpg extension too, but no lucky.

Comment: The result is not the same. It should at least be shorter.  If itt isn't, you haven't done it correctly.

Comment: @Aron, you are right, the previous file size was 76KB, after i made the change you said, is 74KB. But still seems corrupted.

Comment: @Marcos I suggest you have the same problem at the sending end.

Comment: @EJP, what you mean ?

Comment: I mean that the part of the application that is *sending* the email has the same problem in the copy loop as per this answer.

Comment: As described in the JavaMail FAQ, use the [saveFile method to save the attachment](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#readattach).  If the saved file is not exactly the same as the one you sent, we're going to need more details about how you're sending the file, how you're saving the file, how you know they're not exactly the same, and how you're checking whether the file is "correct".

Comment: @BillShannon, this is what i do: i open my email software (Thunderbird) and in the email body i do paste an image that is captured via windows snip tool (i do not save the file in my disk and attach it to the email. i directly paste the image from the memory to the email body). after that, i run my java program that read that email and have to detect this inline image, and save it to my local disk. The image seems to be saved, but when i try to open it, windows says it is corrupted.

Comment: If you read the message with Thunderbird and save the image, what do you get?

Comment: @BillShannon,i did the test, and the file is saved as an image and not as html.i can open it and see the image. I think the problem is, that when i send the email, and read the inline from java, i should do some kind of search of image, so i can just take the images and not other html stuff., but i am not sure how to get it done

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you mean by "inline image"?  Is the image data embedded in the html data?  Or is the image a separate MIME body part in the message with a Content-Disposition that says "inline"?  If the former, then yes, you'll have to parse the html and extract the image data and JavaMail isn't going to help you with that.  If the latter, you should be able to save that image "attachment" directly, as described above.